# How to sync a folder with Amazon S3 using aws php sdk?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I not only want to upload files to s3, but also want to remove those deleted files from s3.

For example, I have these 2 files on s3: black.jpg, red.jpg

I have these files in my local directory: black.jpg, green.jpg

I want a function that will upload green.jpg to s3 and delete red.jpg from s3. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Get an array of files with `$s3->listObjects();` and a array of local files with `readDir();`

`$uploadList = array_diff($localFiles, $s3Files); // returns green.jpg`

`$deleteList = array_diff($s3Files, $localFiles); // returns red.jpg`

Loop over `$uploadList` and call `$s3->putObject()`

Loop over `$deleteList` and call `$s3->deleteObject()`

---

Check out AWS PHP SDK documentation for the necessary method parameters.

- [listObjects Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingObjectKeysUsingPHP.html)
- [putObject Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpPHP.html)
- [deleteObject Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DeletingOneObjectUsingPHPSDK.html)